# Where could I find complete documentation of zurb-foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

How (and where) to get the completed documentation of zurb-foundation. I am using Zurb's Foundation 3 and got the doc from http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/index.php. However, some of the docs are missing, such as the one for form validation. In the foundation cases, it shows that a form element can have a required attribute or an input element can have a type equals email. But when I submit the form (in my application), it will auto validate and I can't get any docs about it.

Where I can find additional documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zurb documentation is complete. I guess that given that Zurb offers such a rich framework we all expect Foundation to include full form validation.

The Framework [does not include](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/117) a [form validation javascript](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/586), just form validation **aware** forms which are greatly described in the Zurb Documentation.

Having said that I have done validation usin the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). It takes a little bit of puzzle solving to get the thing fully sorted but I guess the code below should provide some initial guidance on how to fully use the Validation statuses offered by Foundation 3.0:

```
<form id="contactForm">
   <div class="five columns">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength='40' name='First Name' class='required' minlength='2'/>
   </div>
<form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactForm").validate({
      errorElement: "small",
      highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
         $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
         $(element).parent().children("input").addClass(errorClass);
      },
      unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
         $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
         $(element).parent().children("input").removeClass(errorClass);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

The keys are:

** Use jQuery validate classes to define the validation rules, use the options `highlight` and `unhighlight` to add/remove the error class to the input element being validate and specify the `errorElement` to paste the error message within a `<small>` tag instead of a label.

Hope this helps